# Android - will users trust embedded webview for twitter authorization?

Tags: android

Will users trust if I use an embedded webview to authorize my app with twitter? I could obviously be providing a fake page to catch their login. Or do they expect me to launch a browser so they can see the url etc? If I do that, is there any way to automatically return to my app when finished? How do other apps handle this? Expecting the user to press the back button after they're done isn't very graceful, as the oauth process involves about 3 page redirects in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Users seem to trust an embedded webview, especially if you place it in a "pop-up" dialog. We have done that in some of our apps (http://larvalabs.com). Once authorized, it is possible to get a callback to automatically return to your app, sparing the user the hassle. See for example this approach:

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/08/08/improved-twitter-oauth-android/